# PHP text outside of li

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a wordpress theme and for some reason my list of pages are showing outside the li when I view the source

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <?php 

        while ( $queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post(); 
            echo sprintf('<li>%s</li>', the_title());
        endwhile; 

    ?>
</ul>
```

And when I review the source in the inspector in chrome

```
<ul class="tabs">
    Deans’ Corner<li></li>
    Education Plan<li></li>
    Counselors’ Corner<li></li>
</ul>
```

I got to be missing something simple

Comment: I'm guessing `the_title()` actually echoes the title instead of returning it.

Comment: There may be something going on in `the_title()`, but you haven't posted that.

Comment: @HoboSapiens that is a wordpress function

Comment: [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Comment: @jrock2004 It's not a good idea to put solutions in the question. If nothing below actually answers your question, add your own answer.

Comment: @Mike - I did get the answer and it was from TimoSta

Comment: @jrock2004 It would be better to add a comment to that answer, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for `the_title()`:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

> Displays or returns the title of the current post.
>
> [...]
>
> $echo
>
> (Boolean) (optional) Display the title (TRUE) or return it for use in PHP (FALSE).
>
> Default: TRUE

`the_title()` takes an optional parameter `$echo` which decides whether it should return or echo the title of the page. Since you did not fill it and it defaults to the echo option, your code does not work.

Comment: Yeah, I just started reading that. I was able to do the_title('<li class="btn btn-tabs">', '</li>');

Comment: In summary, do this instead: `the_title('<li>','</li>');`

Comment: Or use the method that is actually intended to return the title: `get_the_title()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

This way it is more obvious what is actually happening. Otherwise the echo is hidden behind a function with a title that in no way indicates that anything will be `echo`ed.

Answer (score 1):

If the_title() echoes, you won't be able to use it directly with sprintf().

Therefore, you can do just use HTML...

```
<li><?= the_title(); ?></li>
```

---

The below example is unnecessary because of the_title()'s optional parameters as pointed out in Timosta's answer.

Or you can use output buffering if you need to use the_title() as a function argument:

```
ob_start()
the_title();
$title = ob_get_clean();
echo sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $title);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that by default `the_title()` echos the title instead of returning it. You can actually specify what to echo before and after the title so there is no need for using `sprintf()`.
This should work:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <?php 

        while ( $queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post(); 
            the_title('<li>', '</li>');
        endwhile; 

    ?>
</ul>
```

Check the WordPress Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Comment: This has already been covered in a previous answer/comments.